# SpecialFolder.ApplicationData not working in .net MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui, create-directory

I cannot get my directories made to AppData/Roaming while using this code in .net MAUI:

```
        RootLocation = new DirectoryInfo(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/MyApp");
        SaveLocation = new DirectoryInfo(RootLocation.FullName + "/saves");
        SaveLocation.Create();
        BackupLocation = new DirectoryInfo(RootLocation.FullName + "/backups");
        BackupLocation.Create();
```

However if I change SpecialFolder.ApplicationData to SpecialFolder.Desktop it does work on Desktop. It seems to be a permissions issue however in Visual Studio 2019 using WPF I can still save to AppData/Roaming. Could this be an issue with Visual Studio 2022 Preview?

Comment: MAUI isn't a runtime, it's a UI library. What runtime are you using?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "not working"? Does it throw an exception? Does it return `null`?

Comment: @Dai It does not throw an exception. SpecialFolder.ApplicationData returns the proper path to "../AppData/Roaming" however no directory is created. Right now just for Windows (win32 runtime if i'm not mistaken). Using System.Environment for the create directory calls.

Comment: `new DirectoryInfo` does not create a directory, you need to explicitly call `.Create()`.

Comment: @Dai I believe I do explicitly call them with "SaveLocation.Create();" and "BackLocation.Create()", as it works when I use SpecialFolder.Desktop. It is only SpecialFolder.ApplicationData that is not working.

Comment: @Dai For now I have switched to using "SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData", which saves to C:\ProgramData/MyApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (IsWindows())
{
    savingPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyVideos);
    savingPath = Path.Combine(savingPath, "yourfolder");
    if (!Directory.Exists(savingPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(savingPath);
    }
}
```

I think it will be better. And the code is running correctly on my desktop and my Android app

Answer (score 0):

By default, Maui apps are not allowed to access `SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` in the normal location.  This is because of app virtualization and containerization.

Maui compiles on Windows as a WinUI3 appx/msix.  It's configured with special "[file system virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-desktop6-filesystemwritevirtualization)" that changes where files are written.  In particular, when you try to write to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming` it instead writes to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\package_id\LocalCache\Roaming` or [some variant in the Packages directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes#appdata-operations-on-windows-10-version-1903-and-later).  The justification for this is it allows the uninstaller to completely remove all of the app's resources.

Fortunately, the virtualization can be disabled by adding the following to your project's `Platforms\Windows\Package.appxmanifest`:

```
<Package
 ...
 xmlns:desktop6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10/6"
 xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
 IgnorableNamespaces="... rescap">

  <Properties>
    ...
    <desktop6:FileSystemWriteVirtualization>disabled</desktop6:FileSystemWriteVirtualization>
  </Properties>

  <Capabilities>
    ...
    <rescap:Capability Name="unvirtualizedResources"/>
```